# Proof verification: eigenvectors remain the same and eigenvalues are raised to the nth power when multiplying by matrix $A^{n-1}$

Tags: solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is my attempt at proving the following: Suppose $A\overrightarrow{x}=\lambda\overrightarrow{x}$, then it follows that $A^n\overrightarrow{x}=\lambda^n\overrightarrow{x}$ where $n$ is a positive integer, $\lambda$ is some real number, and $A$ is a matrix.

Proof: We attempt a proof by induction, beginning to prove the case for $k=2$:

\begin{aligned}
A^2\overrightarrow{x} &= A(A\overrightarrow{x})\\
&=A(\lambda\overrightarrow{x}) \\
&= \lambda(A\overrightarrow{x}) \hspace{3mm} \text{(as $\lambda$ is a scalar)} \\
&=\lambda^2\overrightarrow{x}
\end{aligned}
We now assume the result is true for some $n=k$ and use this to show it holds true for $n=k+1$. Thus, we have that
\begin{aligned}
A^k\overrightarrow{x} &=\lambda^k\overrightarrow{x} \\
A^{k+1}\overrightarrow{x} &=\lambda^k(A\overrightarrow{x}) \\
&=\lambda^{k+1}\overrightarrow{x}
\end{aligned}
By the induction hypothesis, we are done.

Is this proof ok?

Comment: You are spot on. Proof is perfectly in order.

Comment: how do you know there are no other eigenvectors/eigenvalues other than those of $A$?

Comment: Your proof, as it relates to the eigenvalues, proves something different than what you've stated in your title.

Comment: As a proof that $A^n\vec{x}=\lambda^n\vec{x}$ for (amongst others) all positive $n$, your proof does not address the case $n=1$. Which is of course trivial, but that should make you think that your base case could (and should) be chosen a lower one. Finally, it is suspicious that your inductive case is _shorter_ than your case $n=2$, which it shouldn't be. Look carefully, an argument that you needed for $n=2$ is missing from your inductive case.